# How to correctly use an IF statment to add a specific WHERE condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I am not so into database and I have a problem working on a **MySql** query that involve an **IF** statment.

I ahve this litle query (that works fine):

```
(LCZ1.country_id = (SELECT LCZ2.country_id FROM Localization AS LCZ2 WHERE LCZ2.id = 5))
```

that return an integer value (1 or 2) into **LCZ1.country_id**.

I want to use an IF statment to do something if the returned value is 1 and something else if it is 2.

I was trying to do something like this (this IF statment should add an AND condition to a WHERE clause):

```
IF(LCZ1.country_id = 1)
BEGIN
AND
     LCZ1.country_id is not null
END

IF(LCZ1.country_id = 2)
BEGIN
AND
     LCZ1.country_id is not null
END
```

But it seems to be wrong, it go into error.

What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Can’t you just combine the clauses with AND and OR like usual ones?

Comment: Post your complete query

Comment: If LCZ1.country_id = 1, then it can't be null...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below mentioned query

```
SELECT case 
when LCZ2.country_id is null then 'null'
when LCZ2.country_id = 1 then 'something1'
when LCZ2.country_id = 2 then 'something2'
end as output
FROM Localization AS LCZ2 
WHERE LCZ2.id = 5;
```

Note: 1. LCZ2.id is not null
2. Change whatever you want in something1, something2 and null

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you. Don't mind that i have declared a variable. Replace it with your column.

```
DECLARE @LCZ2.country_id varchar(20)
set @LCZ2.country_id=(SELECT LCZ2.country_id FROM Localization AS LCZ2 WHERE LCZ2.id = 5))
IF(@LCZ2.country_id= 1)
BEGIN
   set @LCZ2.country_id= 'not null'
END
IF(@LCZ2.country_id= 2)
BEGIN
   set @LCZ2.country_id= 'not null'
END
```